# XGBoost RayTaskError

Tags: python, pyspark, distributed-computing, xgboost, ray

I am trying to do model training and inferencing in Databricks clusters using the Ray framework.

I have the following example with the xgboost-Ray example. I have generated ray dataset from parquet file and the following code for model training runs fine.

```
import time
from xgboost_ray import RayDMatrix, RayParams, predict, RayFileType
import xgboost as xgb


start_time = time.time()
train_set = RayDMatrix(data=ray_dataset, label="rz_flag")
evals_result = {}
# Train the classifier
bst = train(
    params=xgboost_params,
    dtrain=train_set,
    evals=[(train_set, "train")],
    evals_result=evals_result,
    ray_params=RayParams(
        num_actors=10,
        cpus_per_actor=10,
    ),
    verbose_eval=False,
    num_boost_round=10,
 
)
print(f"Total time take : {time.time() - start_time}")
bst.save_model("model.xgb")
```

But, when I try to predict the same data, as follows:

```
pred_set = RayDMatrix(data=ray_dataset, label="rz_flag")
bst = xgb.Booster(model_file="model.xgb")
pred_ray = predict(bst, pred_set, ray_params=RayParams(num_actors=10))
print(pred_ray)
```

I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RayTaskError(TypeError)                   Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-4498259778197045>:6
      4 pred_set = RayDMatrix(data=ray_dataset, label="rz_flag")
      5 bst = xgb.Booster(model_file="model.xgb")
----> 6 pred_ray = predict(bst, pred_set, ray_params=RayParams(num_actors=10))
      7 print(pred_ray)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7860245a-9444-406f-9785-d28c042241fe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost_ray/main.py:1850, in predict(model, data, ray_params, _remote, **kwargs)
   1848 while tries <= max_actor_restarts:
   1849     try:
-> 1850         return _predict(model, data, ray_params=ray_params, **kwargs)
   1851     except RayActorError:
   1852         if tries + 1 <= max_actor_restarts:

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7860245a-9444-406f-9785-d28c042241fe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost_ray/main.py:1752, in _predict(model, data, ray_params, **kwargs)
   1749     wait_load.extend(_trigger_data_load(actor, data, []))
   1751 try:
-> 1752     ray.get(wait_load)
   1753 except Exception as exc:
   1754     logger.warning(f"Caught an error during prediction: {str(exc)}")

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7860245a-9444-406f-9785-d28c042241fe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ray/_private/auto_init_hook.py:24, in wrap_auto_init.<locals>.auto_init_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     21 @wraps(fn)
     22 def auto_init_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
     23     auto_init_ray()
---> 24     return fn(*args, **kwargs)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7860245a-9444-406f-9785-d28c042241fe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ray/_private/client_mode_hook.py:103, in client_mode_hook.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    101     if func.__name__ != "init" or is_client_mode_enabled_by_default:
    102         return getattr(ray, func.__name__)(*args, **kwargs)
--> 103 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7860245a-9444-406f-9785-d28c042241fe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ray/_private/worker.py:2493, in get(object_refs, timeout)
   2491     worker.core_worker.dump_object_store_memory_usage()
   2492 if isinstance(value, RayTaskError):
-> 2493     raise value.as_instanceof_cause()
   2494 else:
   2495     raise value

RayTaskError(TypeError): ray::_RemoteRayXGBoostActor.load_data() (pid=15518, ip=10.24.105.6, actor_id=3a58cdcb9d79bbb5c535340702000000, repr=<xgboost_ray.main._RemoteRayXGBoostActor object at 0x7f6852dc3a00>)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7860245a-9444-406f-9785-d28c042241fe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost_ray/main.py", line 639, in load_data
    param = data.get_data(self.rank, self.num_actors)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7860245a-9444-406f-9785-d28c042241fe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost_ray/matrix.py", line 928, in get_data
    self.load_data(num_actors=num_actors, rank=rank)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7860245a-9444-406f-9785-d28c042241fe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost_ray/matrix.py", line 913, in load_data
    refs, self.n = self.loader.load_data(
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7860245a-9444-406f-9785-d28c042241fe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost_ray/matrix.py", line 651, in load_data
    local_df = data_source.load_data(
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7860245a-9444-406f-9785-d28c042241fe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost_ray/data_sources/ray_dataset.py", line 61, in load_data
    data = [data[i] for i in indices]
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-7860245a-9444-406f-9785-d28c042241fe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost_ray/data_sources/ray_dataset.py", line 61, in <listcomp>
    data = [data[i] for i in indices]
TypeError: 'Dataset' object is not subscriptable
```

Can someone explain to me what is happening here? Thanks in advance!